# CSS3 - Animating a sprite-grid

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I've been trying to understand the CSS animation property, I've got this sprite gridsheet I need to run through, I've seen examples of Animations both in row and grid style, but when I try to apply and adapt to my sprite sheet I'm having issues with the display.

Here is my current CSS & Html:

```css
.logo {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/df0nhzq7v/image/upload/v1484325835/bvd2_1024_fxwhvl.png') left top;
  -webkit-animation: playv .6s steps(6) infinite, playh 1s steps(6) infinite; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes playv {
  0% { background-position-y:   0px; }
  100% { background-position-y: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes playh {
  0% { background-position-x:   0px; }
  100% { background-position-x: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/BenSagiStuff/pen/ZLOJKM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple issues at play here. The first is that your animation property has the incorrect values. You need to change it from:

```
animation:
  playv .6s steps(6) infinite, 
  playh 1s steps(6) infinite;
```

to:

```
animation: 
  playv 5s steps(5) infinite,
  playh 1s steps(7) infinite;
```

It's important that the steps function takes in the correct parameters, such that playv is contains the number of sprites there are in the y direction and playh contains the number of sprites there are in the x direction. The timing for playv also needs to be slow enough to animate the grid properly and is actually equivalent to being your duration multiplied by the amount of rows in the sprite grid. This can be simplified into the following formula:

```
animation: 
  playv (duration * rows) steps(rows) infinite,
  playh duration steps(cols) infinite;
```

Secondly, the image you have provided as the sprite grid is too large. It contains blank space/padding to the right and bottom of the image. As a result of this, the following lines are calculated incorrectly:

```
@-webkit-keyframes playv {
  0% { background-position-y:   0px; }
  100% { background-position-y: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes playh {
  0% { background-position-x:   0px; }
  100% { background-position-x: 100%; }
}
```

You either need to update the sprite grid so that it matches perfectly, or specify the pixels exactly like so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes playv {
  0% { background-position-y: 0; }
  100% { background-position-y: -550px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes playh {
  0% { background-position-x: 0; }
  100% { background-position-x: -903px; }
}
```

[Here's the working codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZgegp)

Comment: I see! Thank you for explaining the animation property!